# Prefetch images shown by a CachedNetworkImage

Tags: networking, flutter, prefetch

Flutter's `CachedNetworkImage` is nearly magic, but it would be better if they offered a way to download the images before having to show them. I want to download images in one screen and show them in another one with `CachedNetworkImage`. If the prefetch attempt failed, `CachedNetworkImage` should behave as usual, downloading and caching the image.

Is there any common way of prefetching images in Flutter?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `precacheImage` for adding to image to flutter's image cache.

`precacheImage(CachedNetworkImageProvider(imgaeUrl), context)`

Ps: I'm on mobile I'll edit and format this when I got access to my system.

Comment: I tried it, but it seems that `CachedNetworkImage` doesn't use images precached by  `precacheImage()`. It seems that it works with regular `Image`, but not with the cached ones :·|

Comment: This answer works for me. Precaching `CachedNetworkImageProvider` is working with `CachedNetworkImage`.

Answer (score 1):

Precache CachedNetworkImage like below code

```
Image myImage;
bool _loading = true;

@override
void initState() {
myImage = Image(
  image: CachedNetworkImageProvider("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"),
);
myImage.image
    .resolve(ImageConfiguration())
    .addListener(ImageStreamListener((_, __) {
  if (mounted) {
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
  }
}));
super.initState();
}

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();
  precacheImage(myImage.image, context);
 }
```

And use myImage as Widget. _loading tells you that image is loaded or not.